# how to includeJsFile in head instead of body

Tags: files, includejs

I am using this code to include a js file, but it adds to the `<body>`:

```
{% includeJsFile '/path/script.min.js' %}
```

I need to add it to the `<head>` instead, how can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`getFootHtml`](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/functions#getFootHtml) function to tell Craft where to output HTML queued up with `includeJsFile` and `includeJs`. You'd normally have that tag somewhere at the end of your `<body>`. But all it does is to get all queued up HTML and output it, so if your JS are already "included", you can use it in `<head>`.

Another thing you could do is to not use the `includeJsFile` function to add the HTML to the `<head>`, but use a different approach. Here's an example using a var and an example using a dedicated Twig block:

index.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% set headHtml = '<script src="{{ url('assets/javascripts/myscript.js') }}"></script>' %}

{% block head %}
    {{ parent() }}

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ url('assets/javascripts/myscript.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

base.html

```
<head>
    {% block head %}
        <!-- Document head -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        {% if headHtml is defined %}
            <!-- Scripts -->
            {{ headHtml }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endblock %}
</head>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can queue files with `includeJsFile`, `includeJs` and output `getFootHtml()` anywhere on your page.

Once you've called `getFootHtml()` the queue will be cleared allowing you to use `includeJsFile` again later in your template i.e. both in the `head` and `body`.

*This doesn't appear in the documentation.*